# How to write on a camera device

Tags: interoperability, hardware, input-devices, driver

I am trying to use a USB camera which is made with a CMOS sensor, there are some parameters that can be set for the camera as gain and some others, the problem is talk with the sensor (APTINA MT9P031) some of the parameneters to change can be modified in the mathematica configuration for the device

[image]

The main problem is that i want more control, Can someone explain me how to make my own image capture, is there any usefull tutorial to add more parameters to the control panel
[image]